# c++ templates : syntax of template-parameter-key

Tags: c++, c++11

Ref: In c++ working draft (n4527) 14.1

syntax of type-parameter:

```
    type-parameter-key ...(opt) identifier
    type-parameter-key identifier(opt) = type-id
```

what is optional here - please some one provide me example with option
and what is the use case of it ??

```
       template<typename = int>  // this is complied in vs2015 
       void fun(int x){
        }
        int main(){
               fun(10);
        }
```

Comment: Check out the last example on wikipedia's [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) page.

Comment: From the top of my head: Container adapters. For instance, std::stack<int> actually corresponds to std::stack<int,std::deque<int>>, the latter having been defaulted. Also, the standard containers accept an additional template parameter specifying the allocator to be used. So, std::vector<int> actually corresponds to std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> . You can change these template arguments, but most people don't need to, hence they're defaulted. Hopefully, I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type-parameter-key ...(opt) identifier(opt)
```

This is to support variadic templates, i.e. templates which have an arbitrary number of template arguments:

```
template <typename        > //neither optionals
template <typename...     > //opt 1
template <typename    Args> //opt 2
template <typename... Args> //both
```

These have myriad uses, an example being factory methods:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T make_t (Args&&... args) {
    return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

---

```
type-parameter-key identifier(opt) = type-id
```

This is to support template parameters with default arguments:

```
template <typename   = void> //without optional
template <typename T = void> //with
```

Default template arguments also have wide usage. A good example is allocators for the standard library containers:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;

std::vector<int> a; //same as std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
```

Another example is for using SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct has_foo<T, std::void_t<T::foo>>
: std::true_type{};
```